# How to multiply 2 columns in 2 pandas data frames by each other

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have 2 data frames like this

```
    DF1:    Col1 Col2
    Row1    A   30
    Row2    B   40

    DF2:  Col1 Col2
    Row1    A   10
    Row2    B   5
```

Now i want to multiply DF1.Col2 and DF2.Col2 and get an output like this

```
    Out:   Col1 COl3
    Row1    A   300
    Row2    B   200
```

How can I do this. I try bellow code but its not working

```
DF1[:,'Col3'] = pd.Series(DF1.Col2.astype(int)*DF2.Col2.astype(int),index=DF1.index)
```

This direct to bellow error:
TypeError: unhashable type

Comment: try DF1['COL3] = DF1.Col2.astype(int)*DF2.Col2.astype(int)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need:

```
DF1['Col3'] = DF1.Col2.astype(int)*DF2.Col2.astype(int)
print (DF1)
     Col1  Col2  Col3
Row1    A    30   300
Row2    B    40   200
```

Another solution with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
DF1['Col3'] = DF1.Col2.astype(int).mul(DF2.Col2.astype(int))
print (DF1)
     Col1  Col2  Col3
Row1    A    30   300
Row2    B    40   200
```

Comment: Glad can help! Are data  strings, so necessary convert to ints?

Comment: Yes those are String s.